# Chrome passwords/data

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, path

Does anyone know where Chrome passwords/data files are saved on Linux?
I would like to move them with a symlink to my encrypted folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All user specific data is stored in `~/.config/google-chrome` or `~/.config/chromium` ( most likely to be in the first location). Check for the `Default` folder under this location.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to also grab `~/.pki/nssdb` which is the new NSS "standard" location, which ultimately all NSS apps (Firefox, Thunderbird, Chrome, etc) will use, so that you don't have to install certificate authorities for each and every app.

So far, Chrome doesn't support client SSL certs (AFAIK), but when it does you'll probably want to have this private data in the encrypted folder too (so it will end up double-encrypted, not a problem).

If you're after protecting privacy from other people who might nose around, not just protecting the passwords, then you might want to move `~/.cache/google-chrome/` somewhere, though perhaps to its own encrypted folder  which you can blow away more readily and not have to worry about any fragmentation when you do so.

Comment: FWIW, these days Chrome does support SSL client certs.